# Custom Transparent NavigationBar with back button

Tags: ios

I want to show only a button with a transparent nav bar on a google map just like the Uber app does.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. In order to avoid downvotes please edit the question posting your code or listing your efforts you made to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

In that case just hide navigation bar on your map page and put back button on top left like uber